# Gradle not building after updating Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, facebook-android-sdk

[image]

Please help with this. Is the problem with version of sdk?

Answer (score 1):

In your project, open
**your_app | Gradle Scripts | build.gradle**

Add the Maven Central Repository to build.gradle before dependencies:

```
repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
```